# Get Facebook Following and Follower list using Facebook Graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get all Facebook following users list (which I am following) and follower users list from Facebook using Graph API, I am Googling little bit but did not get anything.

Can any one help me to find the solutions.

Answer (score 1):

This isn't possible with any application v2.0+ and higher. The `user_subscriptions` permission has been removed.

Comment: Thanks @phwd...

Can you please tell me the procedure to get all of my following pages or user? Can I get them by calling some of APIs, Or this is not possible right now..?

Comment: @biswajitGhosh you can get all pages you follow with `/me/likes` you cannot get users you follow.